# rxAndroid retrofit get result of each call from the sequence

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have to execute 3 API calls in the sequence 
 and to do so 
I use `observable.concatMap(new Func1<>...)`
and at the last one I have a subscriber to change `activity`

However I want to update progressBar in UI thread to let user know that part of task is done.

```
private void getAllData() {
    updateUserTask(
        getUserScheduleObservable(
            getCurrentUserObservable()));
}

private void updateUserTask(Observable<TaskWrapper> observable) {
    wrapObservable(observable)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<TaskWrapper>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(TaskWrapper taskWrapper) {
                openCurrentFragment();
                hideProgressIndicators();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            }
        });
}

private Observable<TaskWrapper> getUserScheduleObservable(Observable<ScheduleWrapper> observable) {
    return observable.concatMap(
        scheduleWrappers1 -> apiManager.getRouteObservable(vehicleDeliveryAreaRiderBundle.getVehicle().getId()));
}

private Observable<ScheduleWrapper> getCurrentUserObservable() {
    return apiManager.getUserObservable().concatMap(
            user -> apiManager.getCurrentScheduleObservable()
        );
}
```

Comment: please, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like this.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> first = Observable.just("First");
        Observable<String> second = Observable.just("Second");
        Observable<String> third = Observable.just("Third");

        Observable.concat(first, second, third)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(this::updateProgress)
                .subscribe();
    }

    private void updateProgress(String s) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Notify your progress that %s ended", s));
    }
}
```

Just concatenating those observables, you can achieve the expected result.

Hope that it helps.

Best regards.